# Google Fusion Tables Card Layout: How to format fields

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have the following template:

```
{template .contents}
<div class='googft-card-view' style='font-family: sans-serif; height: 17em; width: 450px; padding: 4px; border: 1px solid #ccc; overflow: hidden'>
    <table border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Village:</b> {$data.formatted.Village}<br>
            <b>Location:</b> {$data.value.Location}<br>
            <b>Location Accuracy:</b> {$data.value['Location:Accuracy']} meters<br>
        </td>
    </table> 
</div>
{/template}
```

Which gives me:

```
Village: TestVillage
Location: <Point><coordinates>69.1782913000,34.5338741600,1787.5000000000</coordinates></Point>
Location Accuracy: 5.0 meters
```

I'd like to be able to get rid of the `<point>`, `<coordinate>` tags, and format the values.  Javascript is disabled/stripped out in the card layout.

How can I manage this, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

{$data.value.Location |noAutoescape}

See [Closure template docs](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/functions_and_directives) for details.

You can't easily get to the individual lat/lng inside a KML snippet, but this should have the effect of clipping out the point and coordinate tags (I think).

If this not sufficient you can take over full formatting of the info windows in your own JavaScript code, though that's a bit more work.

Comment: Brilliant.  That stripped off the tags.  Thanks.  You did mention that I can take over full formatting - where do I see that, because JS code gets stripped out in the card view.

Comment: Here's an example of doing your own info windows: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/infowindow_driving_directions